# Edit String in PHP before being added

Tags: php, replace

I have a system that writes a XML file.

The problem is that I cannot have in the XML file this symbol `&`

I need to replace this symbol wherever it is find in the code with `&amp;`

The problem is I have a LOT of strings, and I do not want to apply a function that will replace that symbol for EVERY SINGLE string I have.

This is an example:

```
$stringData ="<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n";
$stringData .="<ingrooves_import xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xsi:schemaLocation=\"http://schemas.ingrooves.com/INgrooves/INgroovesImport_1_0.xsd\" schema_version=\"1\" schema_revision=\"0\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns=\"http://schemas.ingrooves.com/INgrooves/INgroovesImport_1_0.xsd\">\n";
$stringData .= "<album>\n";
$stringData .= "<title>".$albumTitle."</title>\n";
$stringData .= "<label_reference>LA0001</label_reference>\n";
$stringData .= "<performer>".$MainArtist."</performer>\n";
$stringData .= "<catalog_number>".$CatalogueNumber."</catalog_number>\n";
$stringData .= "<upc>".$UPC_EAN_JAN."</upc>\n";
$stringData .= "<release_date>".$releaseDate."</release_date>\n";
$stringData .= "<copyright>".$DigiDistYear."</copyright>\n";
```

And I have many more of $stringData in my code. So you can understand I do not want to apply for every $stringData a code that will replace that symbol.

I want to find a way to tell to the code, that for any $stringData variable, and for any content this $stringData will encounter, then it must replace `&` with `&amp;`

Is there a way of doing it?

In few words, the code should do so:

For every content you are going to encounter inside the variable $stringData, from now on, you should change `&` with `&amp;` everytime you encounter this symbol.

Please help me!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end of the script, when you finished adding code to the string, add the following:

```
$stringData = str_replace ('&','&amp;',$stringData);
```

You can do also with regular expressions but this will work aswell :-)

Comment: At the end? Not at the top? Won't it write it in the wrong way if I put that in the bottom? SHould not it be a rule to follow before writing anything?

Comment: No, because this search every single & after is executed so you need to actually have ampersands in the string for this to work. You have to use it just before you are going to output to a file or in an echo, or whatever.

Comment: Thanks. Does not it require to be additional $stringData .= instead of $stringData = ? Thanks

Comment: Nope because what you are going to do is replace the dirty string with the "cleaned" string. If you use .= you will end having both strings (the dirty and the cleaned) in the same variable and, as far as I understood, that's not what you want!

Answer (score 2):

This might be too far fetched... but what about simply using [`str_replace`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) after building your XML output?

```
$stringData = str_replace('&','&amp;',$stringData);
```

Note:

This would replace even an already existing `&amp;` to `&amp;amp;`, so make sure you don't already have some `&amp;` in your string before using this line of code.

Answer (score 0):

use this, and it should work fine:

`$stringData = str_replace('&','&amp;',$stringData);`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood your question correctly.

Basically, at the end of the assignment, you replace all occurences of & inside stringData with &

```
$myString = "this is a test & you &&& can & see";
$newString = str_replace('&', '&amp', $myString);
echo $newString;
```

In the new variable, you can see that all & and repalced now with &

You can not see the results in a browser because the browser will display all & as &

You need to look at the code or test the code in a terminal.